# I Want to edit and add data in json file using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, fs

I am new to angular js.i google but dose not found something helpful.

this is my retails.json file:

```
{

    "categories": [

        {

            "dept_id": "123",
            "category_name": "database",
            "category_discription": "list of database",
            "current time": "2016-07-21 06:27:17",
            "id": "1"

        },

        {
            "dept_id": "1234",
            "category_name": "debugging",
            "category_discription": "program debugger",
            "current time": "2016-07-21 06:32:24",
            "id": "2"

        },

        {

            "dept_id": "12345",
            "category_name": "system analyzer",
            "category_discription": null,
            "current time": "2016-07-21 06:33:23",
            "id": "3"
        }

    ]

}
```

I want to make a form using angularjs that  will edit and delete some to this json file.how can i do this?...also this json file is running on my loclhost.how can i edit and add some data to this json file if it is running on localhost?i am using node js to run this file on localhost.

This is my nodejs file i.e running on localhost.

```
   var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var fs = require("fs");
  var http = require("http");
 var cors = require('cors');
 var router = require('router');

  app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, content-    type");
 next();

});

   app.get('/categories', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "retails.json", 'utf8', function (err,   data) {
    console.log(data);

        res.send(data);
  });
})

  var server = app.listen(8081, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

and this is my test.htm file:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <style>
       table, th , td  {
       border: 1px solid grey;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       padding: 5px;
       }
       table tr:nth-child(odd) {
       background-color: #f1f1f1;
       }
       table tr:nth-child(even) {
       background-color: #ffffff;
       }
      </style>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8  /angular.min.js"></script>
      <body>

      <div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="customersCtrl3">
      <frame>
      <table border="1">
      <b><tn>categories</tn></b>
      <tr>
      <th>dept_id</th>
      <th>category_name</th>
      <th>category_discription</th>
      <th>current time</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in categories">
      <td>{{ x.dept_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.category_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.category_discription }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.currenttime }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
       </tr>
       </table><br>
       <table border="1">
       <b><tn>departments</tn></b>
       <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Address_info</th>
       <th>currenttime</th>
       <th>Id</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="x in departments">
       <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.address_info }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.currenttime }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
       </tr>
       </table><br>

       <table border="2">
       <tr>
       <th>dept_id</th>
       <th>phone</id>
       <th>mobile</id>
       <th>email</th>
       <th>web></th>
       <th>facebook</th>
       <th>twitter</th>
       <th>linkedin</th>
       <th>current time</th>
       <th>id</th>
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="x in digital_marketing">
       <td>{{ x.dept_id }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.phone }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.mobile }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.email }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.web }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.facebook }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.twitter }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.linkedin }}</td>
       <td>{{ x.currenttime}}</td>
       <td>{{ x.id }}</id>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </div>

       <script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp2', []);
     app.controller('customersCtrl3', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get("http://localhost:8081/categories").then(function (response) {
      $scope.categories = response.data.categories;//departments
     $scope.departments = response.data.departments;//digital_marketing
    $scope.digital_marketing = response.data.digital_marketing;
  });
  });
    </script>

     </body>
     </html>
```

now i want to edit and add data to json file by using angularjs.i want to show like this: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_w3css

Comment: are you created a view for this?

Comment: pretty sure you can't, have to do this server side

Comment: no view. i am new to this...forget server side.just tell me how can i dow it....i want to do like this: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_w3css

Answer (score 1):

Require the json file using `require()` and perform some modification :

```
var jsonObj = require('./test.json');
```

Modify the `jsonObj` as you want, create a new object or whatever, then write the file:

```
fs.writeFileSync("test.json", jsonData);
```

Note:if you are planning to parse big JSON objects use a streaming json parser.